# Stella Boleto erro ao carregar jrxml

Tags: java, caelum-stella

Estou tentando gerar boleto com [Stella](http://stella.caelum.com.br) mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro

```
Exception in thread "main" br.com.caelum.stella.boleto.exception.GeracaoBoletoException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream
at br.com.caelum.stella.boleto.transformer.GeradorDeBoleto.<init>(GeradorDeBoleto.java:62)
at br.com.caelum.stella.boleto.transformer.GeradorDeBoleto.<init>(GeradorDeBoleto.java:72)
at Teste.main(Teste.java:69)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:249)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:229)
at br.com.caelum.stella.boleto.transformer.GeradorDeBoleto.<init>(GeradorDeBoleto.java:60)
... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C3F786D
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:244)
... 4 more
```

Estou usando a classe padrão que está disponível no [github](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/wiki/Downloads-do-caelum-stella).

Acho que esse erro está sendo causado por que o arquivo está em algum formato errado, porem foi o que veio no pacote na pasta template.

Comment: Conforme o erro, seu arquivo está corrompido. Tentou baixá-lo novamente?

Comment: Sim, já tentei. o arquivo é um jrxml do JasperStudio

Comment: Então pode ser que esteja corrompido no arquivo fornecido por eles mesmo. Pegue o JRXML do repositório e compile novamente, pode ser que dê certo.